ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token at doubleCsrf
First off, sorry this is a re-upload. reason being is I'm an idiot...
I'm creating a dummy social media app using express JS and Mongoose. I tried to implement sessions and CSRF protection but I am experiencing a lot of issues with CSRF. No matter what I try I keep getting the error in the title. Here is my App.js file:
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const { doubleCsrf: csrf } = require('csrf-csrf');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const User = require('./models/users');

const MONGODB_URI = SENSITIVE

const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: MONGODB_URI,
    collection: 'sessions',
});
const csrfProtection = csrf({
    getSecret: () => 'supersecret',
    getTokenFromRequest: (req) => req.body._csrf,
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const mainRoutes = require("./routes/main")
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'my secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: store,
    })
);
app.use(cookieParser('supersecret'));
app.use(csrfProtection.doubleCsrfProtection);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return next();
    }
    User.findById(req.session.user._id)
        .then((user) => {
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});


app.use(mainRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URI)
    .then((result) => {
        app.listen(3001);
        console.log("connected")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

Here is how im utilizing it in my EJS forms:
<form action="/signup" method="POST">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>" />
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </form>

I've tried different things such as clearing browser cache and using CSRFSync and nothing has worked :( it seems like the error all falls back to line:
const csrfProtection = csrf({
    getSecret: () => 'supersecret',
    getTokenFromRequest: (req) => req.body._csrf,
});

I'm quite new to backend work so if anyone is able to give me some pointers ill be very appreciative :)
